# How can I formulate two dimensional arrays in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

how can I formulate two-dimensional array-oriented program TwoDimMatrix that will produce the given output TY :)

Sample output:

```
1 10 11 20 21  
2 9  12 19 22  
3 8  13 18 23  
4 7  14 17 24  
5 6  15 16 25
```

Comment: Why do you need arrays for this?

Comment: I always have 12345 instead of vertical

Comment: @JustinSanGabriel "I always have 12345 instead of vertical" <- This is a matter of presentation aka how you output your two dimensional array and has nothing to do with how you create it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think out there must be a lot of better solutions than this, but you can try it:

```
int[][] array = new int[5][5];

int value = 1,  flag = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if (flag == 0) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            array[j][i] = value++;
        }
        flag = 1;
    } else {
        for (int j = 4; j >= 0; j--) {
            array[j][i] = value++;
        }
        flag = 0;
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array[i]));
}
```

This snippet will print your desired output.

Comment: Ty very much :) <3